# Integrating asp.net with Drupal

Tags: c#, php, .net, drupal

I am looking for suggestions and links towards integrating asp.net with Drupal. I will be taking a current site which houses an asp.net application that makes uses of mssql server. In the clients new site they want it to be in Drupal and thus php.

So, in summary - *how would I build a Drupal site while integrating the .net application that currently exists?*

Answer (score 0):

Just throwing this out there, for the data access areas of the existing .NET site you could possibly expose them as a service. Thus, in the backend php of Drupal you could Create, Update, and Delete objects through the .NET service methods. Could you explain a little more about the role the .NET site takes after the Drupal integration is complete. You said that is utilizes a SQL Server, to what extent? Would this database be used to populate website content such as images or descriptions and other textual content?

Comment: This .net application and respective database is used to store data, that is then displayed on the site via drop down boxes, check boxes....basic user input/interaction. It then pulls that information and returns a result (in this case a location or set of locations).